# xml examples not working- keep getting same error "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "hello.xsd" >"

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

This is the "hello.xml" document.  I am using jedit on a Mac, and I'm following this book's example called ineasysteps.  I'm not sure if my code is wrong or is it my editor or what?  I tried using sublimetext editor but that was a nightmare because it seems like the xml file is not reading the dtd file.  Thanks for your help

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!-- XML in easy steps - Page 46. -->

<doc xmlns:xsi=
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemaInstance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "hello.xsd" >


<msg>Hello World!</msg>

</doc>


 hello.xsd-----------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>

<!-- XML in easy steps - Page 46. -->

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >


 <!-- DECLARE ELEMENTS. -->
<xsd:element name="doc" type="docType"/>
<xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string"/>

<!-- DEFINE STRUCTURE. -->
<xsd:complexType name="docType">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="msg"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML, the namespace uri is incorrect.

Instead of:

```
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemaInstance
```

it should be:

```
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
```

Example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!-- XML in easy steps - Page 46. -->

<doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hello.xsd">

    <msg>Hello World!</msg>

</doc>
```

Comment: So i tried to add the XMLSchema-instance, but i still get the same error. The error reads like this: 7:cvc-complex-type.3.2.2:Attribute 'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is not allowed to appear in element 'doc'/

Comment: Try copying and pasting the XML from my answer exactly.

Comment: WHOOOOAAAA ThANKS !!!! THAT WORKED, I'm not sure why yours worked perfectly and mine did not.